# How to access Github through firewall playing man-in-the-middle when using https?

Tags: git, https, proxy, github, firewall

I need to access Github for read and write access. Earlier I just used plain http protocol which worked fine. But today this does not seem to work anymore.

My problem: I am behind a firewall where only http access is possible. https access seems to be quite tricky because the firewall acts as a man-in-the-middle: It decrypts all SSL traffic from/to the internet and encrypts it again with its own certificate for the user. This certificate can be extracted from the installed web browsers.

Is there a way to setup a working connection to GitHub under these conditions? If yes, how can it be done?

Kind regards,
Marcus

Comment: You might want to crosspost this question to superuser.com. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally got it work with https by setting `git config --global http.sslVerify false` so the company certificate is ignored.